# FindResource can not file resource, however, LoadString can load it

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, resources

I am trying to get string resource length with `FindResource`/`SizeofResource` functions.

I make call like this:

```
HRSRC hResInfo = FindResource(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(resourceId), RT_STRING);
```

I receive `NULL` and `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND`.

Now I use the same variables to make following call:

```
LoadString(hModule, resourceId, buffer, 4096)
```

And string is loaded successfully with the same `hModule` and `resourceId`.

So, I can load string resource, but can not find it with `FindResource`. 
What may be the reason? How to find string resource with `FindResource` (and hence get its size)?

Comment: FindResource w/ RT_STRING is not as simple as that as they are stored in blocks; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720259/how-do-you-open-a-resource-string-in-visual-c-2010

Comment: Just to clarify, the string identifiers are NOT the same as the resource ID.

Comment: As others pointed out, `RT_STRING` gets you `STRINGTABLE` resource, and not individual string. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/30/65013.aspx

Comment: Thanks, friends, I see now how to get what I want.