# What is the meaning of MAKEINTRESOURCE((id>>4)+1)?

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, atl

I am trying to mimic the behavior of `CString::LoadString(HINSTANCE hInst, DWORD id, WORD langID)` without introducing a dependency on MFC into my app.  So I walked through the source.  The first thing it does is to immediately call `AtlGetStringResourceImage(hInst, id, langID)`, and then this in turn contains the following line of code:

```
    hResource = ::FindResourceExW(hInst, (LPWSTR)RT_STRING, MAKEINTRESOURCEW((id>>4)+1), langID);
```

(It's not verbatim like this, but I trimmed out some unimportant stuff).

What is the meaning of shifting the ID by 4 and adding 1?  According to the documentation of FindResourceEx, you should pass in `MAKEINTRESOURCE(id)`, and I can't find any example code that is manipulating the id before passing it to `MAKEINTRESOURCE`.  At the same time, if I make my code call `MAKEINTRESOURCE(id)` then it doesn't work and `FindResourceEx` returns null, whereas if I use the above shift + add, then it does work.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: String table resources are stored in groups of 16 based on the string ID. 
Shifting by 4 bits is essentially the same as dividing by 16. 

Raymond Chen has a great explanation on his blog.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040130-00/?p=40813

Comment: You don't need to fiddle with raw resources. [LoadString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadstringw) does this for you already, as illustrated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33336980/1889329) answer.

Comment: Except LoadString doesn't take a language id, which I specifically need for my use case.  LoadString instead uses the current thread locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [STRINGTABLE resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/stringtable-resource) documentation:

> RC allocates 16 strings per section and uses the identifier value to determine which section is to contain the string. Strings whose identifiers differ only in the bottom 4 bits are placed in the same section.

The code you are curious about locates the section a given string identifier is stored in by ignoring the low 4 bits.