# Building application with different language specified in resource.rc

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I never done something like this, so this is my first attempt. From reading online different information and tutorials, I can confidently say that I got very confused so I went on my own with this.

What I am trying to achieve is have different build configurations with different languages for the GUI.

My application is Win32 built using Visual Studio 2019.

Steps I tried:

- Cloned my existing Release build
- Opened up my .rc file in Notepad++ and cloned the "default" language
  sections
- Changed the language macro in the cloned sections ( *LANGUAGE 
  LANG_VIETNAMESE, SUBLANG_DEFAULT*)
- Translated everything from Menu, Dialogs, etc.
- Reloaded in visual studio, and I can see 2x set of all resources. (
  menu, dialogs, everything in 2 sets - 1 english and 1 vietnamese )
- Opened up project propierties -> Resources and changed Culture to
  Vietnamese
- Built the project successfully

However the result is nothing. The menu and dialogs are still in English.

Is there something else I must do to specify which set of resources to use to obtain a different language build ?

Or am I over complicating this and going all wrong...

Any advice/examples are much appreciated.

Comment: You need to look at where you load resources from the RC file and call `FindResourceExA` with the appropriate language ID https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-findresourceexa

Comment: @RichardCritten Interesting, I'm looking at this.

Comment: @RichardCritten This does seem to be what I need, however I got no clue how to use this properly...

Comment: @NorbertBoros [This](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18/Multilingual-Application-Change-Application-Langua) is an old case. I'm not sure if it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I will answer my own question because I believe others have hit this problem as well.

**The correct and official way** to change the language of a Windows GUI applications is:

[SetThreadUILanguage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-setthreaduilanguage)

Using this function, and the exact thing I did in my question; the function will apply the resources in that language at runtime. ( menu, dialogs, everything )

I my case it was as simple as:

```
SetThreadUILanguage(MAKELANGID(LANG_VIETNAMESE, SUBLANG_VIETNAMESE_VIETNAM));
```

However in my case I am creating builds per language, so if you want to allow the user to change the language at runtime please see the notes and [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170908-00/?p=96965).

**The un-official way** of doing this is a bit more work, however quite stable and not error prone.

- You must translate and rebuild your menu in that language
- You must translate and rename each dialog ID per language, and show that dialog ID per language

For the community and other developers, I will share the code to rebuild the menu:

```
// Find our Menu resource based on desired language
HRSRC hRes = FindResourceExW(hInstance, RT_MENU, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_APPLICATION), MAKELANGID(LANG_VIETNAMESE, SUBLANG_VIETNAMESE_VIETNAM));

if (!hRes) {
    wchar_t buf[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)), NULL);
    MessageBoxW(0, buf, _TEXT(L"FindResourceExW Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    return FALSE;
}

// Load our Menu resource based on desired language
HGLOBAL hGlo = LoadResource(hInstance, hRes);

if (!hGlo) {
    wchar_t buf[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)), NULL);
    MessageBoxW(0, buf, _TEXT(L"LoadResource Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    return FALSE;
}

// Lock the resource
LPVOID pData = LockResource(hGlo);

if (pData == NULL) {
    wchar_t buf[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)), NULL);
    MessageBoxW(0, buf, _TEXT(L"LockResource Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    return FALSE;
}

// Load the new Menu into memory
HMENU hMenu = LoadMenuIndirectW((MENUTEMPLATE*)pData);

if (!hMenu) {
    wchar_t buf[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)), NULL);
    MessageBoxW(0, buf, _TEXT(L"LoadMenuIndirectW Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    return FALSE;
}

// Get our default Menu
HMENU hMenu_old = GetMenu(g_Hwnd);

// Set no Menu
SetMenu(g_Hwnd, NULL);

// Erase default Menu
DestroyMenu(hMenu_old);

// Set our new Menu
SetMenu(g_Hwnd, hMenu);

// Draw our new Menu
DrawMenuBar(g_Hwnd);
```

**NOTE**: If you want to use **FindResourceEx** to search for strings, it's more complicated because of **RT_STRING** so please [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720259/how-do-you-open-a-resource-string-in-visual-c-2010) before you waste your time.

Enjoy!